# Web Audio API: discover a node's connections

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

With the Web Audio API, is there a way to discover a node's connections?

For example, given

```
ctx = new AudioContext();
g1 = ctx.createGain();
g2 = ctx.createGain();
g1.connect(g2);
```

is there a method I can call on `g1` that will return `[g2]`?

I'm interested in writing a javascript library to visualize the current audio graph, similar to the [Firefox Web Audio Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Audio_Editor).

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
var connect = AudioNode.prototype.connect;
var disconnect = AudioNode.prototype.disconnect;

AudioNode.prototype.connect = function( dest ) {
  this._connections || ( this._connections = [] );
  if ( this._connections.indexOf( dest ) === -1 ) {
    this._connections.push( dest );
  }
  return connect.apply( this, arguments );
};

AudioNode.prototype.disconnect = function() {
  this._connections = [];
  return disconnect.apply( this, arguments );
};
```

This is a quick example, and it doesn't account for `disconnect` arguments. But something along those lines could work, I think.

There are good reasons *not* to do something like this. But 
it *would* allow you to keep the application code generic, which is really what you need if you want to be able to visualize arbitrary audio graphs.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what are the good reasons not to do this?

Comment: The main reason, and why I wouldn't recommend this, is because this changes the expected behaviour of a built-in. As soon as you add a library or someone else uses your code there's an increased chance of hard to debug bug's. This would also unexpectedly increase the memory usage for someone who isn't aware that it's being done, which could be an issue in audio applications. Better make the tracking a standalone feature. It's fine if it's just a quick demo etc. but it's a bad practice that you should probably avoid.

Comment: Granted, the memory impact would be minimal in all cases I can think of, but still. :)

Comment: Note also that connections can go away by themselves and that won't be captured here.  If a source node is finished playing, the system can automatically disconnect that from the downstream node.  You can kind of track this using the onended event, but I'm not exactly sure when the auto-disconnect happens.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no - there is no such method. You'll have to keep track of your connections yourself.